Allowed host django settings
Hola hace poco descubrí lo que se puede dockerizar tus aplicaciones para produccion y desarrollo y es super optimo ya que apenas necesitas recursos para ello.
Hoy empeze a dockerizar mi proyecto django pero a la hora de conectarme me da el error de Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'django'. You may need to add 'django' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Por lo que he estado investigando esto se puede arreglar agregando hosts a la lista ALLOWED_HOST del archivo settings.py por lo que he puesto lo siguiente:
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0']

Pero me sigue dando el mismo error, que debo añadir en allowed host, la ip del contenedor, localhost, la ip de la maquina anfitrion, las 3? No tengo idea si alguien me lo puede explicar, un saludo

Esta lista de ALLOWED_HOST lo que hace es crear un arreglo con los hosts que pueden enviar solicitudes al servidor Django. Si quisieras que cualquiera pueda acceder a los servicios, que no es lo recomendable, lo configuras con un *
ALLOWED_HOST=['*']
Esto lo puedes hacer mientras realizas pruebas pero ya en producción debes especificar el host o lista de host que pueden consumir los servicios de tu Api.
Por tanto, esta lista es una medida de seguridad para evitar ataques de suplantación de host o que personas no autorizadas accedan a tus servicios.
Cuando Dockerizas una aplicación Django y la ejecutas en un contenedor, es probable que la configuración predeterminada de Django para ALLOWED_HOSTS no incluya el nombre de host que Docker asigna al contenedor. Esta parte es muy importante porque debes conocer como se esta exponiendo el contenedor, esto podria ser por la ip asignada al mismo o por el nombre que le asignaste en el docker-compose.yml en caso de que estes usando compose o si es con kubernets acá si es un poco más complejo porque el pod recibe una ip dinámica en ese caso ya necesitas otro enfoque como el usar variables de entorno.
Retomando, tu duda puntual de agregar 'django' a ALLOWED_HOSTS, con esto estás permitiendo explícitamente que las solicitudes con el nombre de host 'django' sean aceptadas por tu servidor Django. Esto funciona bien para pruebas locales o configuraciones específicas de Docker donde el nombre de host se establece como 'django' por defecto. Sin embargo, en entornos de producción real, debes configurar ALLOWED_HOSTS con los nombres de host reales que se utilizarán en producción para garantizar la seguridad de tu servicio.
Por ejemplo, si tu aplicación se va a ejecutar en un dominio específico o en una ip que conozcas lo configuras en el array de ALLOWED_HOST=['192.168.1.100', 'myapp.com']

Por ejemplo mi dominio donde se va a hostear la web es anthonyx82.ddns.net por lo que debo añadir ese nombre a la lista de allowed_host

Finalmente leyendo detenidamente el error se podía leer lo sigiente:
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'django'. You may need to add 'django' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Por lo que he puesto: ALLOWED_HOST=['django'] y ha funcionado sin errores, igualmente no se exactamente que es o que hace esta lista si alguien sabe mas info la agradeceria

Siempre hay que revisar la documentación.
